# Firestore python query throwing ValueError: Path `number-field` not consumed residue: -number

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I am playing around with Firestore for the first time and I am using Python 3.9.5

I have successfully added data to my database in python using:

```
        addDoc = db.collection('My-Collection').document()
        addDoc.set(val)
```

where val is a json object.

However when I try to query the collection on `number-field`:

`docs = db.collection("Keno-Games").where("game-number", "==", 373).stream()`

This was copied from the firestore console query creator where it does work, but it doesn't when I try to use it in my python code. The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/timbolton/Desktop/kenoApi/kenoFirestoreIngest.py", line 21, in <module>
    docs = db.collection("Keno-Games").where("game-number", "==", 373).stream()
  File "/Users/timbolton/Desktop/kenoApi/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/base_collection.py", line 243, in where
    return query.where(field_path, op_string, value)
  File "/Users/timbolton/Desktop/kenoApi/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/base_query.py", line 278, in where
    field_path_module.split_field_path(field_path)  # raises
  File "/Users/timbolton/Desktop/kenoApi/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/field_path.py", line 84, in split_field_path
    for element in _tokenize_field_path(path):
  File "/Users/timbolton/Desktop/kenoApi/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/field_path.py", line 64, in _tokenize_field_path
    raise ValueError("Path {} not consumed, residue: {}".format(path, path[pos:]))
ValueError: Path game-number not consumed, residue: -number
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

Field Paths cannot contain the `-` character as per the [Documentation - Constraints on Field Paths](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields) :

> - Must separate field names with a single period (.)
> - May be passed as a string when all field names in the path are simple, otherwise must be passed as a FieldPath object (e.g. JavaScript FieldPath)
> - A simple field name is one where all of the following are true:
>   Contains only the characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and underscore (_)
> - Does not start with 0-9